# HtmlDropDownList SelectList is a list of Model and how to display models Property

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, webgrid, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a webgrid and inside it each item has different selectList which consist of model. I want to display name of that model. How can I do that

```
grid.Column(header: "AvailableDevices", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("value", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)item.AvailableDevices)),

List<XXModel> myList = new List<XXModel>();
item.AvailableDevices = new SelectList(myList );
```

and XX model has property of Name, Age etc. And I want to display name or Age in my dropdown List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of `SelectList`:

```
item.AvailableDevices = new SelectList(myList,"Id","Name" );
```

[**See all Available Contructors of SelectList**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks :) What about if we want to get all attributes is it also possible?

Comment: Hi Also do you know how do we get the selected values of it? I would be glad

Comment: if it is strongly typed view it will be posted in model in form post